# q-menu wont show up under button on mobile devices

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

Here's the code pen
https://codepen.io/ruskoiscool/pen/WNYxqgV?editors=101

```
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-sm">
    <q-btn :loading=true color="purple"label='get data button'>
      <q-menu><span>hello</span></q-menu>
      <template v-slot:loading>
        <q-spinner-radio />
      </template>
    </q-btn>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you inspect the element then change to a phone the q-menu will no longer show up
when the button is clicked.
What's strange is if I put a button right next to it, it will work.
Also, the default spinner shows the q-menu when it's clicked in mobile.
However I need to have a different spinner and show the menu when the button is clicked,
and it needs to work on a tablet.
is there a way to achieve this?